# MySQL junction table not updating after creating keys

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, junction-table

I first created 2 tables.  Later I realized I needed to add a M:M relationship between the two, so I created a junction table and created the necessary relationships between the tables.  The problem I'm running into is that after creating the junction table, it isn't automatically being populated with the data from the other 2 tables.  Should this data be automatically pulled from the other tables, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're explicitly `INSERT`ing into the junction table, it's not going to go in there.

Of course, you could potentially use `triggers` for what you want to achieve.

Comment: @user1476992 no worries, remember to mark the answer as correct if it suits the question :)